# MediaControllerCompat get state doesn't return the current position

Tags: android, mediacontroller, android-mediasession

In my code

```
MediaControllerCompat.setMediaController(MainActivity.this, mediaController);
mediaController.registerCallback(mCallback);
PlaybackStateCompat state = mediaController.getPlaybackState();
```

The *getPosition()* in *state* is always the one I set in *MediaSessionCompat.Callback* *onPlay* and *onPause* methods.

I want to know how to set the state of *MediaSessionCompat* object so that mediacontroller *getPlaybackState()* returns with the latest position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a valid position only if you update the position parameter and update the `PlaybackState` object.

You can create a looper the wakes up every second and update the `PlaybackState`
with the [setPlaybackState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html#setPlaybackState(android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat)) method.
Create a `PlaybackStateCompat` object with the [builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/PlaybackStateCompat.Builder.html) and use the [setState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/PlaybackStateCompat.Builder.html#setState(int,%20long,%20float)) method to set the position.

Comment: @patos27, what i did in the mean time is to send a custom command 
`mediaController.getTransportControls().sendCustomAction` from Activity to the service which holds media session object and in `onCustomAction` update the playback state which sends back the new state to `onPlaybackStateChanged` method of `MediaControllerCompat.Callback` object in Activity. As such it meets my requirement. Do you think that's a good idea?

Comment: @AsheshBharadwaj yeah, sounds good. This way you'll only update the state when needed and not if the activity is in the background for example

Comment: You don't need to update the PlaybackState every second. The MediaSession remembers the time at which you call setPlaybackState() so when you call getPosition() and the state is playing, it will automatically add the difference between the current time and the last update time to the position (also taking playback speed into account).